# UITableview cell cut off some messages(views)

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview

I have messages screen and implement custom `tableviewcell` for the display message. A message should be `text` or `image` and some case I need to display boxes with information(see image sender and receiver). it's working fine but some time messages view cut off(see image messages). I have used many `stackViews` to hiding and show some views.

Please find the [code here](https://files.fm/u/9ktvf5rr) for more understanding.

[image: sender] 
[image: receiver] 
 [image]

Comment: I will be appreciated for any help.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot **from the viewdebugHierarchy** of when you click on the cut off textField? I want a screenshot like the one I took [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793420/why-isnt-uibutton-returning-correct-constraints). I want to see the _constraints_ (which in my image are on the right side) of the cutoff view.

Aside from all this, it would be better if you post your question with more related screenshots of the constraints/frames you set for the cells in the xib + code of the constraints you set in the code. It would make it easier for us to help.

Comment: did you give it a try?

Comment: @Honey. not yet, will share you today. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

The possible cause for such a behaviour is setting up the layers of the view in cell, I can see in your cell, you are adding the corner radius to the background. I could be able to fix it in my app by using the following approach.

1. Define a optional data varibale in your cell.

   ```
   var currentData: MessageModel?
   ```
2. set that value in the method you are calling to provide the data to cell.

   ```
   func loadData(_ data:MessageModel) -> Void {
   currentData = data

   // YOUR EXISTING CODE GOES HERE.

   // Move your code to the function which do the setup of corner radius.

   // Call this method.
   setupCornerRadius()
   }
   ```
3. Add the following methods to your cells

   ```
   open override func layoutIfNeeded() {
   super.layoutIfNeeded()
   setupCornerRadius()
   }

   open override func layoutSubviews() {
   super.layoutSubviews()
   setupCornerRadius()
   }

   func setupCornerRadius() {
   if let data = currentData {
       let strMsg = data.body ?? ""
       lblMsgBody.text = strMsg

       if strMsg != "" {
           viewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.primaryGreen
           if strMsg.count > 5 {
               viewBG.layer.cornerRadius = 18.0
           }else{
               viewBG.layer.cornerRadius = 12.0
           }
       }
       else{
           viewBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Try the above approach.

Along with that what I did was, I removed the stackView from the cell and managed to implement the required UI by setting up the constraints.

Label with numberOfLines = 0 and setting Leading, Trailing, Bottom and Top constraints. with value = 8 (You can set it as per your margin and spacing you needs.)

Try and share the results.

Comment: I have used stack view for manage `collection view`, `Buttons View` and `display some information` in the cell when no connection then it shows `no connection yet` view, other view display collection. Have you faced the same issue when you are using `statckview`?

Comment: First you should try commenting the layer related codes from all the cells and then scroll the cells up and down too fast on your iPhone to check if you observe any cutting of the cells or not. Later, you can go for stackView related modifications. In my case, yes, I was observed that same cutting of the cells. So, I first removed stackView, used layout by setting up proper constraints and *then added the layer related code in those two methods* and that fixed the issue. However, you should First check for layers and then move to stackView to identify the possible cause.

Comment: @ilesh does it helped? Have you been able to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use UI debugger and see what exactly is going on.