# Conflicting Constraints - Single Label inside superview

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I'm trying to create a **simple** reusable table section header view pictured as such:

[image]

I'd like the height of the label to be resizable and a padding of 10 from the top and bottom.
I keep getting the *conflicting constraint*s error. I don't see why it can't simultaneously satisfy these constraints.

[image]

Also, while experimenting, if I set the height to <= 45, it all works. I'm confused why.

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: 2nd constraint looks suspicious, but it is covered. bottom to bottom doesn't sound correct.

Comment: Apologies for that. I've just updated the image.

Comment: @AlexisO Why does it look suspicious?

Comment: Try to set number of lines to 0 for your label.

Comment: I’ve sent my number of lines to 2 currently, as I only want a maximum of 2 lines to be printed. Why does setting it to 0 matter here?

Comment: @KunalShah you forgot set the leading (or center) constraint of label

Comment: I see. You're treating the safe area as padding. Pretty curious why this doesn't work too but I won't go with this approach regardless. UILabel is centered so you can create the padding by simply increasing the height.  After that you can set constraint based on other views such as `Title Label.top = Other view.bottom + 10`.

Comment: @QuocNguyen I've already set them. It's not in the screenshot because they aren't conflicting.

Comment: @AlexisO The 'other' view is the safe area here. There's no other view.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting constraints on the Safe Area. Especially for table header.

Comment: I'm making the view as a xib file. XIBs inherently come with safe areas. So, if I need to set a padding with the respect to the superview (content view in this case), it gets assigned to its safe area.

Comment: have you set any height constraint on the `contentView` or the `cell` itself? Because in the current screenshot, things look fine. Can you click on the label and take a screenshot like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51793420/why-isnt-uibutton-returning-correct-constraints)

Answer (score 0):

UIview height should be bigger than 65

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough when I set up similar constraints, I was getting a similar error, but when I stretched the view out from the bottom right far enough, the constraint errors went away.  Either way, when I run the app, I wasn't getting an error read out.

[image]
[image]