# How do I add a UIView to a UIScrollView In Swift programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiscrollview, uikit

I am trying to add a view to a `UIScrollView` just using code, but the view doesn't appear in the `UIScrollView` and I'm not sure why. When I added a button or label, they show up.

```
import UIKit

class profileViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var label : UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Profile"
        label.textColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.80, alpha: 1)
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 40)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        return label
    }()
    var scrollview : UIScrollView = {
        let scrollview = UIScrollView()
        scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollview.backgroundColor = .clear

        return scrollview
    }()
    var greyview : UIView = {
        let view = UIView()
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints =  false
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 0.70, alpha: 1)
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray

        return view
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .white
        view.addSubview(label)

        label.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
        label.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

        scrollview.delegate = self

        view.addSubview(scrollview)
        scrollview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        scrollview.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height + 500)


        scrollview.addSubview(greyview)
        greyview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.topAnchor).isActive = true
        greyview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        greyview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        greyview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48219419/9086770

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because your `greyview` doesnt have its `bottomAnchor`. It needs the top and bottom anchors in order to work properly inside the scrollView:

```
scrollview.addSubview(greyview)
    greyview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.topAnchor).isActive = true
    greyview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    greyview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    greyview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
```

Add a widthAnchor, here I centered it in the scroll view but it is up to you to place it how you want it. Also if you add more items just make sure the bottom-most item has a `bottomAnchor` attached to the scrollView `bottomAnchor` or it will not scroll.

Update:

I don't know how you want your `greyview` to look, but if you make the height taller than the `contentSize` of the scrollView it will scroll, and make sure you have the `bottomAnchor`:

```
 scrollview.contentSize = CGSize.init(width: view.frame.size.width, height: view.frame.size.height)

    scrollview.addSubview(greyview)
    greyview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.topAnchor).isActive = true
    greyview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    greyview.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.heightAnchor, constant: 500).isActive = true
    greyview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollview.widthAnchor).isActive = true
```

This makes the `greyview` width equal to scrollview width, and height equal to scrollview height + 500 so that it scrolls.

Comment: i don't add the bottom anchor because i have a height anchor

Comment: try it, it still needs the bottom anchor

Comment: because it is a scrollView it needs to have a bottom anchor otherwise it wont scroll or the content wont display properly

Comment: you tried with the top anchor and the bottom together right?

Comment: yeah i use them all but nothing change

Comment: @OualidHamidi it will appear if you give it a `widthAnchor`

Comment: yeah it appear but when you try to scroll down the scroll doesn't work.

Comment: @OualidHamidi that is because it needs to be attached to the bottom anchor of the scrollView, and also the height would need to be taller than the scrollView.

Comment: as the Scrollview wont scroll if the content inside is smaller than its contentSize, as it does not need to

Comment: @OualidHamidi remove the `+ 500` on your `scrollview.contentSize` and make the height of the gray view `1000` and you will see it will scroll because its height is taller than the contentSize of the scrollVIew

Comment: thank you bro for your support. i find the probleme of why doesn't scroll the issue is when i added the widthAnchor. should i delete trailingAnchor and LeadingAnchor .

Comment: yes delete trailing and leading anchor and replace with widthAnchor

Comment: I did one more update, do it like I did in the update of my answer at the bottom, I think that is how you want it.

Answer (score 0):

this is one way:

```
 self.scrollView = UIScrollView.init()

    if let scrollView = self.scrollView {
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        self.view.add(scrollView)

        scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.addConstraint(UtilConstraint.addTopConstraint(from: scrollView, to: self, value: 0))
        self.addConstraint(UtilConstraint.addBottomConstraint(from: scrollView, to: self, value: 0))
        self.addConstraint(UtilConstraint.addLeftLeftConstraint(from: scrollView, to: self, value: 0))
        self.addConstraint(UtilConstraint.addRightRightConstraint(from: scrollView, to: self, value: 0))

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(self.constraints)

        greyview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scrollView.addSubview(greyview)

        greyview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        greyview.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
        greyview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        greyview.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }
```

Remember, your `greyview` should have hight defined either statically or via. components inside.

though , what you were missing was defining a width. I have done it using widthAnchor. (assuming you need a vertical scroll)