# How to set the height of the content view?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have the following scrollview. Inside the scroll view is a ui view and inside that are sub views and buttons.  dynamically increase the content size of the scroll view to make it fit the content.

```
 self.scrollView.contentSize =  CGSize(width: self.scrollView.contentSize.width, height: self.scrollView.contentSize.height + CGFloat(300))
```

The content view inside the scroll view is not scrolling to the end of the content, so that content gets cut off. What should I do so that I can see all of the content inside the content view?

See attached

[image]

Comment: Are you constraining the top-most view's top anchor to the top anchor of the scroll view and the bottom-most view's bottom anchor to the bottom anchor of the scroll view (among other necessary constraints)?

Comment: How do I do that? @liquidLFGUKRAINE

Comment: I'll be honest, I used Interface Builder for one day and that was it. I think it's one of the biggest piles of junk ever introduced to software developers in the history of programming. So I can't help you with IB, only programmatic, but the concepts are the same. This is your solution.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this programmatically? @liquidLFGUKRAINE

Comment: Sure, this should explain it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48219419/9086770